# Get Next Element with Name Containing

Tags: jquery, find, jquery-selectors

Ok, I have been fighting with this for over an hour so I have to ask. Here is my HTML

```
<a id="edit_shipping">[ Save ]</a>
<span>Method: <input id="new_shipping_method" type="text" value="Free Shipping"></span>
<input type="hidden" name="order_total[1][order_total_id]" value="14">
```

And my jquery

```
$("#edit_shipping").on("click",function(){
   alert($(this).next('input[name*="order_total_id"]').val());
});
```

I can not for the life of me figure out why I keep getting an undefined. I also tried the  find selector and the same results. Please help!

Comment: next only gets the next element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you tell me if it works ?

```
$("#edit_shipping").on("click",function(){
   alert($(this).siblings('input[name*="order_total_id"]').val());
});
```

Comment: He'll end up with a collection of objects if he has any input above or below that a tag.

Comment: alert($(this).siblings('input[name*="order_total_id"]').val()); works too

Comment: $(this).siblings('input[name*="order_total_id"]').val() worked great. Thanks!

Comment: Ok.  Targeting the name makes it more specific.  The first response would be bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use nextAll instead next.

```
$("#edit_shipping").on("click",function(){ 
alert($(this).nextAll('input[name*="order_total_id"]').val());
});
```